# Convert cell values to array in a dataframe based on certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe as follows

```
+--------------------+
| id | index | value |
|----|-------|-------|
| A  | 1     | abc   |
| B  | 1     | def   |
| B  | 2     | abc   |
| B  | 4     | ghi   |
| C  | 2     | jkl   |
| C  | 4     | abc   |
| D  | 4     | def   |
|----|-------|-------|
```

I want to transform it as follows

```
+------------------------+
| id | array             |
|----|-------------------|
| A  | [abc, , , ]       |
| B  | [def, abc, , ghi] |
| C  | [ , jkl, , abc]   |
| D  | [ , , , def]      |
|----|-------------------|
```

the length of the array is equal to the max value in the `index` column
I want to populate the `array[index-1]` with the string in the `value` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with replace missing values to empty strings and then convert rows to lists, also add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `range` between `1` and maximal value of `index`:

```
df1 = (df.pivot('id','index','value')
         .fillna('')
         .reindex(range(1, df['index'].max() + 1), axis=1, fill_value='')
         .apply(list, 1)
         .reset_index(name='array'))
print (df1)
  id              array
0  A        [abc, , , ]
1  B  [def, abc, , ghi]
2  C     [, jkl, , abc]
3  D        [, , , def]
```

Comment: my bad, i haved edited the question to correct my mistake.